# Django ImageField showing absolute Linux path in template

Tags: python, django

I have the following model

```
class Product(SiteBaseFields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0.00)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=0.00)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The product record in the database are

```
d762ugo5f5706v=> select id, image from dj_commerce_product
d762ugo5f5706v-> ;
 id |                                                image
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 17 | /var/www/dj_node_project/media/iphone_4TTsU22.jpg
 19 | /var/www/dj_node_project/media/samsung_phone_5VlDULp.png
 18 | /var/www/dj_node_project/media/201409-w-americas-best-coffee-cities-new-orleans-cafe-du-_CTcGKwx.jpg
(3 rows)
```

When I do `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{product.image.url}}" />` in the template, I get back `<img src="/var/www/dj_node_project/media/iphone_4TTsU22.jpg">`, and the URL to the image is totally wrong. I can't not find out the cause.

Comment: can you show the settings file where you declared the media path

Comment: whats the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py.

```
# settings.py 
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , "media") # this is the root/absolute path for uploaded files
```

Reupload something and check if this works fine. The issue has be related to MEDIA_URL OR MEDIA_ROOT. Its a common beginners mistake to configure MEDIA settings wrong.

**For Reference:**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-url

**Edit:**

> FileField.upload_to This attribute provides a way of setting the
>   upload directory and file name, and can be set in two ways. In both
>   cases, the value is passed to the Storage.save() method.
>
> If you specify a string value, it may contain strftime() formatting,
>   which will be replaced by the date/time of the file upload (so that
>   uploaded files don’t fill up the given directory). For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    # or...
    # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2015/01/30
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Comment: can you remove this `upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT` part ? and see how it works ? cos  I dont see any good reason why you should do that. Just make it `upload_to='some_folder'` .

Comment: upload_to some folder fixed the problem.

Comment: Perfect! Happy to know that. You can mark this as an answer then.